# Design Mobile Button Bar with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I like to create a stylish button bar at the bottom of the mobile view. I like to use the glyph and awesome icon set for it. So I've placed them in a `<span>` tag, but first problem is that they have different sizes and in general they are very small.
I've tried also to use `<button>`s instead of `<span>`, but there is no flow in the design, because the buttons are seperated from each other.

Any ideas or examples how to design this navigation/button bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap nav bar customization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149635/bootstrap-nav-bar-customization)

Comment: please show some code or design you want to make.